# How to fill/calculate a field in ArcGIS 10.5 based on condition of another field using Python

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have three fields in a featureclass. they are `G_landuse` (General Landuse), `detail_lan` (Detail landuse) and `Type`. Some values of `G_landuse` are blank.

1. I want to fill all blank values of `G_landuse` with the word "Waterbody" using the condition where the value for `Type` field is 0.
2. For specific values in `Type` field, I want to fill with specific values in `detail_lan` field. For example: when the value is 2 in `Type` field, the `detail_lan` field should show "pond". and for 3, It should show "canals"

How can I achieve these?

Comment: You can use Field Calculator or Updatecursor. See an example of the cursor [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm#C_GUID-5CBF0F12-3B31-41AC-A525-65829523F692)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You have a task here, not a problem. A problem would show what you have tried, and where you are stuck.